# Cant find .so files in openCV 3.1.0 SDk for android 3.1.0

Tags: android, opencv, .so

I was looking for the .so files on OpenCV 3.1.0 for android to be imported to Android Studio for my App. But I cant seem to find the files.

Answer (score 0):

The file name might have changed, but it is still under the native libs folder, extracted from the OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk.zip archive.

For example, for v7a it is under:

> /OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java3.so